# Intuition Behind $O_p(\frac{1}{n})$

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics

So let's say $X_n = O_p(\frac{1}{n})$.

According to [Wikipedia's definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_in_probability_notation) this means that $\forall \; \epsilon>0, \; \exists$ finite $M>0,N>0$ such that $P(|nX_n|>M)=P(|X_n|>\frac{M}{n})<\epsilon \; \forall \; n>N$.

I am trying to build an intuition and visualize what this means.

Is it fair to say that as $n\to \infty, \;X_n$  becomes arbitrarily small "most of the time" (i.e. except with a very small probability)? And that we are guaranteed for any $y$ and $\epsilon$ (and perhaps a very small $y$ I wish to use to bound $X_n$) there will eventually be some $N$ such that $P(|X_n|>y)<\epsilon \; \forall \; n>N$?

Comment: Be careful, it is $O_p(1/n)$. $O(1/n)$ means something nonrandom.

Comment: @Zhanxiong I have edited the question accordingly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$X_n = O_p(\frac{1}{n})$ means it's not terrible to think of $X_n$ as something like 
$$
Y / n.
$$
This is a single random variable over a changing nonrandom constant.

Indeed $Y/n = O_p(\frac{1}{n})$ because 
$$
P(|Y/n|n > M) = P(|Y|>M) 
$$

can be made arbitrarily small by increasing $M$.

Then there's one more thing to consider. The probability inequality in this definition only needs to hold for $n$ greater than some chosen large $N$. This means that *eventually* your sequence of random variables "feels like" a single random variable over a constant.

Comment: This is true, but what the OP appears to have meant was $O_p(\frac{1}{n})$, not $O(\frac{1}{n})$.

Comment: @jbowman yes sorry about that I have edited the original question

Comment: @Taylor along the same line of your reasoning is it fair to say if $Y$ a r.v. then $\frac{Y}{n}=O_p(\frac{1}{n})$ and in general $\text{Var}[O_p(\frac{1}{n})]$ decreases at a rate of $\frac{1}{n}$?

Comment: This statement could still apply in situations where there are nonexistent/infinite variances.